# How to keep one element fixed and the rest scrolled?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am doing an website where I have to keep one image fixed to the screen and on scroll I want different elements to appear one by one and stick to one position. When this is done I continue to the footer of the website.

I have done tried to reach that but whatever I do the page keeps scrolling and does not wait for all the elements to appear on the screen.

Example of what I want to do can be seen here [Link](https://www.hype.it/Hype/en/) on the second page where the mobile phone it is sticked in the screen  and on scroll different content appear one by one.

How do I achieve this ? What kind of libraries would you suggest?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you post what you've already tried? Also, sounds like you're looking for `position: fixed`

Comment: I tried to put it on codepen but I used a jquery library and it is not shown properly on codepen . 

Yes I tried the position fixed but what about the content. I want the content to come and stick to the top one by one.

Comment: in your css file do. (image{position:fixed}) Try JSbin(Jsbin.com) or   JsFiddle(Jsfiddle.com)

Comment: you can `position: fixed` with css but just be aware there are issues with this and older version of iOS - http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-fixed

Comment: I don't if this is going to work but you can somehow try to utilize overflow: scroll to achieve this. I don't have much idea about how to keep the image fixed but maybe what you can do instead of detecting browser height (which obviously comes with a large margin of error) look for mouse-enter and set fixed on enter and remove it on mouse exit.

Answer (score 1):

stuff like this is usually done with js libriaries, as you already wrote. One that is actively supported and works quite well is *Scrollmagic*. It should be able to do what you describe, at least it can do the stuff in the example you linked: It can "pin" elements on the page for a defined duration (= "scroll duration") or animate elements controlled by the scroll position.

Scrollmagic can be found on Github or here: http://scrollmagic.io/ , examples to be seen here: http://scrollmagic.io/examples/index.html

Comment: Thank you I will check it out

Answer (score 0):

Your fixed html content should have css `position: fixed;`.

Comment: But I don't want it to be fixed through the entire scroll. When I reach the footer for example I don't want that element to be fixed anymore

Comment: Then you'll need to use Javascript to detect when you've reached the bottom and set a different class to it.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried `position: sticky`? There may be browser compatibility issues but there are polyfils out there to fix that.